# How to submit a form in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, forms, angularjs

I have an html form that I am validating with an Angular controller.  If the validation fails, I apply certain classes to the html.  If it passes, I want to let the form submit itself.  Although this seems very straightforward, I haven't found an easy way to do this.  One method I have found uses the `$scope.$broadcast` function to tell the form to submit, however, I am using the `Controller as Ctrl` syntax so I would rather not use `$scope`.  Is there anyway to submit a form from a controller?

My simplified HTML

```
<form ng-controller="LoginCtrl as login" ng-submit="login.validate()" method="post">
    <input ng-model="login.username" />
    <input ng-model="login.password" />
</form>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("LoginCtrl", ["$http", function($http) {
    this.username = "";
    this.password = "";
    this.validate = function() {
        //validate
        if (valid) {
            // somehow form.submit()
        }
    };
}]);
```

I am somewhat new to Angular so forgive me if this is  an obvious quesion ;)

**EDIT**:
I need to clarify that I am looking to avoid submitting the form with AJAX (i.e. `$http.post`).  Basically what I want is the controller equivalent of calling `form.submit()`.

**USE CASE**:
Let me explain exactly what I am trying to do.

```
User arrives at login page
User enters credentials
User hits Submit
    Controller asks server (using api path) if the credentials are valid
    if valid then
        Tell the form to submit to regular login path // how?
    else
        Immediately tell the user they submitted invalid credentials
```

This way the User gets immediate feedback if they entered incorrect credentials.
All of this I have implemented **except** for the actual form submission.

Comment: please have a look at [this blog](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/validations.html) on how to validate forms in angularjs

Comment: Very helpful!  I will definitely consider validating with a directive.  However, it doesn't answer my initial question of programmatically submitting a form in Angular.

Comment: For that you will have to use $http, to post data to server from login controller

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach would be wrap all the form element data into one object. You don't have to create this object if you have no data to prepopulate, `ng-model` will create it for you.

```
<form ng-controller="LoginCtrl as login" ng-submit="login.validate()" method="post">
    <input ng-model="login.MyFormData.username" />
    <input ng-model="login.MyFormData.password" />
</form>
```

This will result in an object in your controller scope looking like:

```
$scope.MyFormData={
   username :'foo',
   password:'bar'
}
```

When ready to submit:

```
$http.post('path/to/server', $scope.myFormData).success(response){
   /* do something with response */
})
```

Comment: Putting the form data into an object is a good idea.  I thought about taking this method, but I would rather be able to tell the form to submit itself instead of having to submit the form with AJAX.  I should have mentioned that in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to have validation as part of your form submission flow. Try something like this:

**HTML**

```
<form ng-controller="LoginCtrl as login" ng-submit="login.submit()" method="post">
    <input ng-model="auth.username" />
    <input ng-model="auth.password" />
    <div class="error" ng-hide="valid">Something is invalid...</div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("LoginCtrl", ["$http", "$scope", function($http, $scope) {
    $scope.valid = true;
    $scope.auth.username = "";
    $scope.auth.password = "";

    var valid = function() {
        // validate

        return valid; // true or false
    };

    this.submit = function() {
        if (valid()) {
            $http.post('/your/auth/url', { auth: auth }).success(function(response) {
                // whatever you're doing to store the auth response.
            });
        } else {
            // use this to conditionally show error messages with ng-show
            $scope.valid = false;
        }
    };
}]);
```

I'm not sure I understand your comment about using the controller-as syntax. That shouldn't change how you use `$scope`.

Comment: Thanks!  However, this doesn't quite answer my question.  I'm wondering how to do the `// submit your form` part from my controller.

Comment: You would need to make use of `$scope` for that. I've updated my answer accordingly. Notice the use of the `auth` object on the scope.

Answer (score 0):

I have an example with the bare minimum code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zeve0BG9sSxSmUMBP87l?p=preview). Note, it is self validating, and you don't even need to submit anything from the COntroller! you can include the action and method fields as form attributes, and angular will submit the form if it is valid

**HTML**

```
<form name="LoginCtrl as loginForm" method="Post" action="not-a-real-script.php">
  <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="loginData.name" placeholder="username" required="" />
  <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="loginData.password" placeholder="Password" required />
  <input type="submit" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" value="Login" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.loginData = {};
});
```

Comment: A good idea, but I am trying to check if the user exists in my database on the backend, so it is not quite the same kind of validation as your code is doing.

Comment: not quite sure what you mean, a login form gets submitted SO the backend can validate the user. I believe you have 2 options: submit form with 'action=script-url' attribute on form like I have, or you use the $http service in your controller as others have suggested

Comment: See updated question.  So there is no way for an Angular controller to tell an HTML form to submit itself?

Comment: You have 2 options. 1) do what i did in my Plunker example above. When the user enters the credentials and hits submit, the form will automatically get sent to your server. Your server can then return redirect message to send the user to the page after the login, or an error if not valid credentials. The other option is to use $http. When the user clicks submit, you send a $http request to the server, and the server responds with a valid/invalid message. Then, inside the angular controller you can use $location service to redirect to the logged in page if login was successful.

Comment: when your inside the controller, there is no point in telling a form to submit itself, if you have ng-submit="loginHandler()",  loginHandler should take care of all the loggin in, the form doesn't do anything else regarding submission at that point