# How to pass userID along with file(multipart) to REST controller through AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, rest

I have a working multipart file upload implementation using AngularJs which sends files to rest controller for storing the files.

**HTML**

```
<form name="myForm" id="loginForm" data-ng-submit="submitForm()">
  <input type="text" name="user_fullname" ng-model="fullName">
  <input type="text" name="Contactnumber" ng-model="number"/>
  <input type="file" data-ng-file-select data-ng-model="item.file" id="document" data-uploader="uploader" data-file-model="myFile" accept="application/pdf" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid"/>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"  data-ng-click="addItem(item.file)" type="button"> Upload </button> <br>
  <button id="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
    app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
                var modelSetter = model.assign;

                element.bind('change', function(){
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    }]);

    app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
        this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', file);
            $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}

            })
            .success(function(data){

                $scope.res=data;
            })
            .error(function(){
            });
        }
    }]);

    app.controller('detailsController',[ '$scope', '$http', 'fileUpload', function($scope, $http,  fileUpload)
          {
               $scope.items = [];
               $scope.item = {};

               $scope.addItem = function (item)                             
                {   
                    if ($scope.item.file != undefined)
                    {
                        $scope.items.push( $scope.item);
                        $scope.item = {};
                        $scope.showTable=true;
                    }
                    else {
                            $('#myModalErr2').modal('show');
                         }
                }
         $scope.submit = function()
                 { 
                            var formData =
                        {
                            fullName     : $scope.fullName,
                            contactNumber: $scope.number,
                        };


                        $http.post('userdetails', formData ).success(function(response)
                            {

                                if ($scope.items.length > 0)
                                  {
                                    for (var i = 0 ; i < $scope.items.length ; i++)
                                    {
                                      $scope.uploadFile($scope.items[i]);

                                    }
                                  }  

            };

        $scope.uploadFile = function(file){
           var file = $scope.myFile;
           var uploadUrl = 'upload';
           fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
        };
```

**REST Controller(For file Upload)**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes={"multipart/form-data"})
    public @ResponseBody void handleFileUpload(MultipartHttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        Iterator<String> itr =  request.getFileNames();
        MultipartFile mpf = null;

        while(itr.hasNext()){

            System.out.println("Inside loop");
            mpf = request.getFile(itr.next()); 

            if(files.size() >= 10)
                files.pop();

            fileMeta = new Document();
            fileMeta.setFileName(mpf.getOriginalFilename());

            try {
                fileMeta.setBytes(mpf.getBytes());
                FileCopyUtils.copy(mpf.getBytes(), new FileOutputStream("D:/temp/files/"+mpf.getOriginalFilename()));

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            files.add(fileMeta);
        }
    }
```

In angular controller, First I'm posting the Name and Contact number to REST and if it is success, An auto generated id will be returned to angular which I'm getting. Point is, how to send this id along with multipart file for storing the file with that particular id?

Comment: Use a `type=hidden` input element or use another `transformRequest` and set it there.

Comment: @PatrickJ.S., Could you please explain in the code? I'm new to this multipart

Comment: Either `fd.append('user-id', userId)` in your fileUpload service. Or `transformRequest: function(fd){fd.append('user-id', userId); return fd}` in your `$resource`. Or you [submit the form](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24843624/801553) with `<input type="hidden" ng-model="userId" name="user-id">`. If you want to have this as some form of authentication, you might want to google `HTTP Authentication methods`, there are of solutions plenty out there, no need to invent a new one.

Comment: I wrote fd.append('file', file); fd.append('id', id); in service. When I checked by putting breakpoint, id is shown as object, not integer value. What could be the issue?

Comment: @Protagonist regarding your "id object not integer value" what are you passing in as the id parameter?

Comment: Problem is fixed. There was a mismatch in declaring and calling the parameters. Thanks.